# How to create a hash from keys array and values array?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have two arrays extracted from a HTML page:

```
@row_left = ['Title:', 'Author:', 'Price:', 'Description:', 'Seller:']    
@row_right = ['The Well-Grounded Rubyist', 'David A. Black', '$34.99', 'A great book for Rubyists', 'Ruby Scholar']
```

How can I combine both arrays into a hash?

```
{
  "Title:" => "The Well-Grounded Rubyist",
  "Author:" => "David A. Black",
  "Price:" => "$34.99",
  "Description:" => "A great book for Rubyists",
  "Seller:" => "Ruby Scholar"
}
```

Comment: What is `@row_left`, what is `@row_right` and what is your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan I'm trying to get the values of a html page of two classes row_left, row_right.
I'm able to get those values from each loop. But I have a requirement where row_left value should be a key, row_right value should be a value in the form of a hash.

Hope this is clear.

Thankyou.

Comment: Could you provide some example data of both, your input and your desired output?

Comment: Sure, @Stefan if you consider the o/p from first loop as: Title:
Author: , 
Price: , 
Description: ,
Seller:  
and let the output of second loop be: The Well-Grounded Rubyist, 
David A. Black, 
$34.99, 
A great book for Rubyists,
Ruby Scholar

Comment: and the expected O/P is like:

{"Title:"=>"The Well-Grounded Rubyist", "Author:"=>"David A. Black", "Price:"=>"$34.99", "Description:"=>"A great book for Rubyists", "Seller:"=>"Ruby Scholar"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for merging two equal length arrays into a hash, I would do this:

```
a = [1,3,5]; b=[2,4,6]
Hash[a.zip(b)]
```

Comment: I have upvoted you. But its not being shown due to lack of reputation point of 15. Anyways, Thanks once again for the answer you saved my day. :)